# Creating tuples variations from a list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I am a relative haskell newbie and am trying to create a list of tuples with an equation I named `splits` that arises from a single list originally, like this:

```
splits [1..4] --> [ ([1],[2,3,4]), ([1,2],[3,4]), ([1,2,3],[4]) ]
```

or

```
splits "xyz" --> [ ("x","yz"), ("xy","z") ]
```

Creating a list of tuples that take 1, then 2, then 3 elements, etc. I figured out I should probably use the take/drop functions, but this is what I have so far and I'm running into a lot of type declaration errors... Any ideas?

```
splits :: (Num a) => [a] -> [([a], [a])]

splits [] = error "shortList"

splits [x]
       | length [x] <= 1 = error "shortList"
       | otherwise = splits' [x] 1
         where splits' [x] n = [(take n [x], drop n [x])] + splits' [x] (n+1)
```

Comment: As you declared, the type of the first parameter is a list. But you don't need the type in the function itself, unless you are pattern matching, rather just the parameter name. In other words, try to replace "[x]" with just "x", the parameter name, which we know is a list. ("[x]" in this case would mean a list with one element, x)

Comment: Even when I try the above, I get a type error: "Could not deduce (Num [([a], [a])]) arising from a use of splits'
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 splits :: Num a => [a] -> [([a], [a])]
      at splits.hs:4:10-39
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [([a], [a])])
    In the expression: splits' x 1"   And I did not believe I had to define splits' in this way, I'm also unsure as to how.

Comment: This 'Could not deduce' error is because you are trying to "add" `[(take n [x], drop n [x])]` and `splits' [x] (n+1)` together, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: In the last line you use the operator "+" which is reserved for Num's or some such types. Think about which operator might better combine the return type.

Comment: Oh wow that was all I needed? Haha it works perfectly! Thank you so much, I guess I'm prone to newbie mistakes like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Haskell-y approach is to use the `inits` and `tails` functions from `Data.List`:

```
inits [1,2,3,4] = [ [],        [1],     [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4] ]
tails [1,2,3,4] = [ [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4],     [] ]
```

We then just zip these two lists together and drop the first pair:

```
splits xs = tail $ zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

or equivalently, drop the first element of each of the constituent lists first:

```
          = zip (tail (inits xs)) (tail (tails xs))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
splits [] = []
splits [_] = []
splits (x:xs) = ([x], xs) : map (\(ys, zs) -> (x:ys, zs)) (splits xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes.

You don't need to have `Num a` class for `a`.

use `[]` or `[x]` as pattern, but not a variable, use `xs` instead.

Use `++` instead of `+` for concatenating lists.

In our case use `(:)` to add list to value instead of `++`.

Add stop for recursion, like additional variable `maxn` to `splits'`

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits [] = error "shortList"
splits xs
       | lxs <= 1 = error "shortList"
       | otherwise = splits' xs 1 lxs
         where
           lxs = length xs
           splits' xs n maxn 
               | n > maxn  = []
               | otherwise = (take n xs, drop n xs) : splits' xs (n+1) maxn
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function that kind of does a part of what you want:

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

which does what it looks like it would do:

```
> splitAt 2 [1..4]
([1,2],[3,4])
```

Using this function, you can just define splits like this:

```
splits xs = map (flip splitAt xs) [1..length xs - 1]
```